# Shape of partly dissolved cube

Tags: physical-chemistry, geometry, models

Let's say you have a cube of some material, and you put it in a liquid that can dissolve that material. After a while you take out what is left of the cube. What shape will you have?

I imagine it will be like a cube with rounded corners. At the corners, there is more liquid around, so it will dissolve faster there. But what is the exact shape?

I am mostly interested in the mathematics used to define how shapes change this way. The cube is just an example.

Comment: Isn't there a  cube below every layer of atoms? If the outer layer of atoms is solved, a new, smaller cube emerges. Still, a sugar cube tend to get less sharp in water if time passes.

Comment: The more it melts the more it will approximate a sphere, the shape that maximises the volume minimizing the surface (assuming the starting shape was a regular cube).  However, I am not aware of models to calculate the exact shape at any time.

Comment: "*At the corners, there is more liquid around, so it will dissolve faster there. But what is the exact shape?*" There isn't any more or less liquid at the corners. It's jsut that if you eat away at the corners in all directions there is less material present so that material ends up completely disappearing first.

Comment: You should try asking on Math SE, but frame the question more mathematically so they don't close it. Like if you have a shape where at every point there is an inward expanding negative hemisphere expanding at a constant rate (the shape is being eaten away at in all directions at every point on the surface at a constant rate).

Comment: Not perpendicular to the surface or else you just end up with a smaller version of the shape. Eating away at every point on the surface in all directions has a net movement of the surface towards towards the current center of mass (COM) for the shape which is towards the center for something like a cube but may be outside the shape for something like a C or U. But since the is constantly shape changing the COM does too so a U might eventually end up as multiple separate spheres.

Comment: @DKNguyen Well, yeah, it's more of a math question. I do know math, but I can't manage to formulate the problem in a well-defined mathematical way.

Comment: @Paul You know, now that I think about it it really does sound like the problem is that you just use the initial object as a surface on which you define as the center of an infinite number of spheres. Then you set the spheres to some diameter based on the timed passed and the rate of dissolution and your final shape is the area enclosed by where all the spheres intersect. You could obviously time step through that on a fine grid and brute force but unsure how you would do that analytically but it might be enough for Math SE to point you at the type of math involved. You could also do it in 2D.

Comment: @DKNguyen there absolutely is more liquid around at the corners - I'm not sure why you'd say there isn't. The rate of dissolution will be limited by diffusion, and the greater amount of liquid around at the corners will cause them to dissolve faster. I would say this is a physics question, because without that knowledge there is no way to specify it as a maths question.

Comment: @N.Virgo My issue with saying "more liquid around the corners" it doesn't actually mean anything because each per unit of surface area is still exposed to the same amount of liquid no matter where it is, nor is the water denser around the corners. What does change is how much volume of cube there is behind it before reaching and exiting another surface. So if you want to say that the ratio of surface area to volume increases as you approach the corners, then okay. But there isn't more liquid touching each mm^2 of surface at the corners than elsewhere on the cube.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipsoid https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxdkcFuGyEQhu88xYgcAg521hu3qiKtlFNulaJceqhqC7M4RiELhsGN8_QdsNNK3QP6mfn-mdmBcw7PGl2YtIdcok1wKHpMzjCg70dyiHaC7QmevkP_7KYX6Lu-X3SrxV3HOOfsqJO4RlXU8VoydvWvWtRJv1m0yeUWgrAD3FvYFe-hTA7BuGS8JU_JtTDCAKgnQRDq25WkBMXt3LtXyzIlVzOciSXMAde9hFsgfdP0uifWhHxGDaEN-zqjZENW_-O1dtzbZFkiOgscimQfJM1ZnkgmmLXMUbL3y9Wcr2y0O4iiKDjI-7aoZLGkieZ9mUSRROptrmINB8Ye3ERr0AabbyMOw1LBrm5neNQ-WwW6YNiUOGq8hC5laUbq_DOK99pKUc_Tp_io4hdr2BNBl3XTy22iD3g3CjIrqEPOqd2STOL4VzcbQCU3MdB8efjWKdqhD2ngW18sVxCiNg5PQ7f4Is99FnkfftcHotH5qNMr__yRdso_aJCoiQ==&lang=sage

Comment: @DKNguyen take a point on the surface of the cube and draw a small sphere around it. That sphere contains more water if the point is at a corner. That seems a fairly reasonable definition of "more water around it", and it's a relevant fact for a diffusion limited process.

Answer (score 7):

The answer depends on the exact nature of the chemistry occurring at the cube's surface, as follows.

For an *etchant* that acts uniformly, any projections sticking out of the surface will be eaten off first because a projection can be attacked from two sides at once. This will turn the cube into a sphere as time goes by. This etchant is called a *leveling etch* because it acts to smooth off the surfaces it attacks.

Now as an etch dissolves away a surface, there will be a natural tendency for the etch rate to depend on the availability of fresh etchant molecules which must diffuse up to the surface through the bulk liquid to attack that surface. By putting other molecules into the etch mix which interfere with diffusion, it is possible to magnify the levelling tendency of the etch to the point where the only thing that gets etched are sharp asperities sticking out from the surface that protrude deep into the liquid- and then you have a *polishing etch* that produces a mirror-like finish.

Alternatively you can imagine an etch which is inhibited by for example the presence of oxygen in solution. If you now have a crevice in the surface, the etch will be accelerated in the crevice because it's difficult for the oxygen to diffuse into the crevice- and you get an etch that preferentially roughens the surface instead of smoothing it. Artful chemistry then allows you to concoct an etch that actively attacks crevices- and you then get what's called an *undercutting etch*.

Undercutting etches can also be devised which create electrochemical *concentration cells* in which the depletion of a reactant component in solution causes the depleted zone to  have a different electronegativity relative to the (smooth) region surrounding the crevice, causing a huge magnification of the corrosion rate at the bottom of the crevice.

So- without knowing what the chemistry of the corrosion process is, you can't predict what shape the cube will evolve into as it gets corroded.

Comment: This is some interesting information. I still hope to get a more mathematical answer for at least one of the cases. I think what I had in mind was a leveling etch, while ignoring the tendency for the etch rate to depend on the availability of fresh etchant molecules.